# How to get the appropriate ComboBox Tag

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to get the Tag associated to a value of ComboBox like this way:

```
var league = ((ComboBoxItem)this.League.SelectedValue).Tag.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(league);
```

The compiler show me a `Invalid Cast Exception`

I only want to get the associated Tag of the selected value by user, in particular:

(combobox value and Tag)
-Italy (item) - 10 (Tag)
-France (item) - 12 (Tag)

If the user select Italy, in the code I must get `"10"`. But I can't do this, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE (Populate combo):

```
List<RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);

        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            foreach (var code in nation_code)
            {
                if (code.Equals(item.League))
                {
                    League.Items.Add(item.Caption);
                    //link for each team
                    League.Tag = item.Links.Teams.href;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is null? `.Tag`?

Comment: The null Exception is now fixed, sorry. The compiler show me: Invalid Cast Exception. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: then the problem is obvious. you can't cast SelectedValue to ComboBoxItem. You could figure out with the debugger wich instance SelectedValue is.

Comment: Okay so how can I get the associate Tag of selected item?

Comment: Use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Same Exception problem.

Comment: How you are populating you combo? Please share the code snippet

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question with population code.

Comment: You need to cast it on whatever RootObject.Caption is

Comment: For WPF you should use -  League.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
League.SelectedValuePath = "Key"; properties instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the Tag is setting for the combo box itself and not for its individual item.

You can build a dictionary and use it as datasource of your combo box. Specify the value and display members of the combo box with dictionary key and value attributes

Try modifying the combo population logic as follows -

```
        List<RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);
        Dictionary<string, string> comboSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            foreach (var code in nation_code)
            {
                if (code.Equals(item.League))
                {
                    comboSource.Add(item.Caption, item.Links.Teams.href);

                }
            }
        }

        League.ValueMember = "Value";
        League.DisplayMember = "Key";
        League.DataSource = comboSource;
```

And then the required values can be fetched using the selectedText and selectedvalue properties.

```
     League.SelectedText; //Return the "item.Caption"
     League.SelectedValue; //Return the "item.Links.Teams.href"
```

> For WPF we need to use different properties viz. `ItemsSource`,
>   `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` while binding the combo
>   box. The above solution is for win forms.

Comment: value member, display member and datasource are underlined in red => ComboBox does not contains ValueMember definition and was not found any method that accept this argument.

Comment: The code is for Windows form application. For WPF, just use the following - "League.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
League.SelectedValuePath = "Key";"

Comment: and for source, ItemSource?

Comment: Yes, `ItemsSource`. Since the question was asked for WPF, maybe the whole answer should be edited to work for WPF instead of WinForms.

Comment: And for get the text of the item selected in the ComboBox?

Comment: @HaroldFinch: You should able to get this using >> string  selectedText =((ComboBoxItem)League.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();

Comment: @HaroldFinch: Or you can simply try using the text propert like - "League.Text"

Answer (score 0):

You can add any type of object to a ComboBox, it does not need to be a string, it just needs to overwrite .ToString().

You could define a class:

```
class League {
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public override string ToString() {
       return Country;
  }
}
```

and then just add these objects to the ComboBox:

```
comboBox.Items.Add(new League { Country = "France", Id = 10 });
```

You can then just cast the SelectedItem of your comboBox back to your class:

```
var selectedLeague = (League)comboBox.SelectedItem;
//access selectedLeague.Country;
//access selectedLeague.Id;
```